20+ errors with "double-quoted include in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead"
I recently updated to Xcode 16.1 and now I am getting 20+ errors with "double-quoted include in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead".
Details about my project

I have installed and updated cocoaPods to the latest version
Firebase is installed however I have another error saying no such module is found even though I can locate it in my Pod Folder.

Thanks for any help!
I have tried

manually changing the imported files from " " to < > but it doesn't fix the problem.
Running rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
pod deintegrate <project_name>
pod update
I have reinstalled my pods and cleaned the build folder multiple times.

